# Should NavigateTo during a Blazor Prerender step throw an exception?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

In my blazor app, I have a page that checks some data in `Task OnParametersSetAsync()` and may redirect depending on the state of that data. On the prerender, I get a generic `NavigationException` when calling `NavigateTo("my/other/page")` and then it runs everything again after the prerender and navigation is successful.

Is this normal? Maybe I should move this check to another place that doesn't run on prerender, but how?

```
// Landing page from a 3rd party. Check if updates to data from 3rd party are ready
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await RedirectIfDataIsReady();

    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal,this page rendered twice. If you want the page disable prerender you could use`@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))`
If you still want page to be prerendered, you could use `IHttpContextAccessor` to check if the code is being prerendered.
If the code is prerendered, "Response.HasStarted" would be false.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor accessor
...
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (!accessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            await RedirectIfDataIsReady();
        };
        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
```